# opengl, help to finish glutmainloop or a function finish

Tags: c, opengl

I have a task...

1.- I am displaying a matrix array using openGL each value is a intensity and its done.
2.- I need to refresh this windows with a new values, BUT the **glutMainLoop()** does not help...

the code is:

void graphfunct(void)

```
    {
/*Here print the array just once and I cannot do the second T_T*/
   }
```

I need to do this code with a new values on u[i][j], the main is:

```
glutInit(&argc, argv);
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE);
glutInitWindowSize(500,500);
glutCreateWindow("1D Function");
glutDisplayFunc(graphfunct);
glutKeyboardFunc(exit);
glutMainLoop();
```

The problem is in the glutMainLoop(); this function in infinity and when start I cannot set new values on u[i][j].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use GLUT timers to call `glutPostRedisplay()` on a schedule or put one at the end of `graphfunct()` to redraw as fast as possible.

Comment: You forgot about the idle function callback of GLUT.